# Print lines after one match and before different match in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to print some lines after some match and before other different match.

Using awk I did it like this:

```
awk '/first match/{f=1} f; /second match/{f=0}'
```

Is any way to do it with PowerShell?

Comment: Use `gc $file -Raw` to read file in then use `-match '(?s)first.*?second'`. You will need to tweak it to get multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to output the second matching line, you can do the following if reading from a file:

```
(Get-Content file).Where({$_ -match 'first'},'SkipUntil') | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -match 'second') {
        $_; break
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
}
```

If you have a variable (`$content`) with an array of lines, you can do the following:

```
$content.Where({$_ -match 'first'},'SkipUntil') | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -match 'second') {
        $_; break
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `Where()` method supports an expression and a mode. The expression, denoted by the script block `{}`, executes against each pipeline object. If your input is an array, `$_` will contain the contents of each line.

`-match` performs a case-insensitive regular expression match by default.

The mode `SkipUntil` means do not output anything until the expression is true. Then continue outputting until all data is processed.

When the second match is found, that line will output and the remaining lines will stop being processed.

The basic workflow is the following:

1. Process the input contents in order starting at index 0 (line 1).
2. Capture nothing until the first match is found (expression evaluates to true).
3. Captured output is piped into a loop until the second match is found. The output includes the second match.
4. Once the second match is found, stop processing data.

---

Alternatively, if you do not need to include the second matched line, the code becomes more concise:

```
(gc file).Where({$_ -match 'first'},'SkipUntil').Where({$_ -match 'second'},'Until')
```

Comment: This code is works untill the first match, but I need all these matches from file. File have a structure like:
1st match
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
2nd match
1st match
olololol
ololol
2nd match